# Why am I getting this data attribute error on Fetch api delete requests?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ejs, fetch-api

I'm using Express/MongoDB/EJS, and I created a function for a fetch api delete request, in hopes to re-use the same function to fetch delete requests throughout the application using two different buttons, but it only works the first time, when I call the function later on in the code with the other button, it throws this Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'delete' of undefined
    at delItem (main.js:42)
    at HTMLElement.<anonymous> (main.js:135)
```

'delete' is the data attribute property im using to grab the ID from the database via button clicks, I have tried using a different property name, recreating a new function, still throws this error no matter what. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong? This is my first time using fetch api, 2 weeks of trying and researching I ask for your help. My code is below:

```
EJS 

<ul id="list">
   <% for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {%>
      <span class="saved-list-item">
          <li class="list-item">
              <div class="checkbox">
                 <span id="circleIcon"><i data-delete="<%= list[i]._id %>" class="far fa-circle uncheck"></i></span>
                     <span id="checkIcon"><i class="fas fa-check-circle check"></i></span>
                                   
              </div>
              <span class="editText"><%= list[i].item %></span>
              <div class="buttons">
                  <button type="submit" data-update="<%= list[i]._id %>" class="saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
                  <button type="button" onclick="window.location.reload()"class="cancelBtn">X</button>
                  <button type="button" data-update="<%= list[i]._id %>" class="editBtn"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
                  <button type="button" data-delete="<%= list[i]._id %>" class="delItemBtn"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>   
               </div>                
          </li>  
       </span>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

Fetch function (this code always works on the delete button, no issues here)

```
const delItemBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.delItemBtn');

for(i = 0; i < delItemBtn.length; i++) {
    delItemBtn[i].addEventListener('click', delItem);
};

for(let u = 0; u < delItemBtn.length; u++) {
    delItemBtn[u].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        localStorage.removeItem(localStorage.key(u)); // LOCAL STORAGE REMOVE ONE
    })
}

function delItem() {
    
    fetch('/list/' + this.dataset.delete, {
        method: 'delete',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    })
    .then(res => {
        if (res.ok) {
            return res.status(200)
        } else {
            res.status(500)
        }
    })
    .then(window.location.reload())
    .catch(console.error)
};
```

Here is where I try to call the delItem() function in hopes to trigger the fetch delete request on a different button via click event, but will not work.

```
for(let i = 0; i < uncheck.length; i++) {
    uncheck[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {       
        if(e.target.classList.contains('uncheck')) {           
            check[i].className = 'fas fa-check-circle check';
            check[i].style.display = 'block';
            uncheck[i].className = 'fas fa-check-circle check';
            li[i].style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
            editBtn[i].style.display = 'none';
            delItemBtn[i].style.display = 'none';
            

            // LOCAL STORAGE SAVE 
            savedChecks = document.querySelector('.saved-list-item').innerHTML;
            localStorage.setItem('checkedItems'+ new Date().getTime(), savedChecks);

        delItem() //Calling the delItem function, but throws the error.

        } 
    });
};
```

Comment: It's probably because of `this.dataset.delete`. It just tells that `this.dataset` is undefined. I also don't see where you have defined this property.

Comment: you also need to pass a function to `.then`, not the result of `.reload()`

Comment: delete property is defined in the EJS codes ```<button>``` and ```< i >``` elements like so  ```data-delete="<%= list[i]._id %>"```  it is how I grab the ObjectID from MongoDB, ```this.dataset.delete``` grabs the data property ```delete``` it works fine with delete button, but not with the click event on the i element.

Comment: Not understanding why the property is defined when using the delItem function on the delete button but it is undefined when calling the function later in the code on a click event...I also fixed the ```.then``` thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by adding a separate event listener in the for loop like so:

```
for(let i = 0; i < uncheck.length; i++) {

    uncheck[i].addEventListener('click', delItem); //Edited code here

    uncheck[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {       
        if(e.target.classList.contains('uncheck')) {           
            check[i].className = 'fas fa-check-circle check';
            check[i].style.display = 'block';
            uncheck[i].className = 'fas fa-check-circle check';
            li[i].style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
            editBtn[i].style.display = 'none';
            delItemBtn[i].style.display = 'none';
            

            // LOCAL STORAGE SAVE 
            savedChecks = document.querySelector('.saved-list-item').innerHTML;
            localStorage.setItem('checkedItems'+ new Date().getTime(), savedChecks);

        } 
    });
};
```

Although it fixed the undefined property, I am still curious why the other way would not read the property correctly.